# error TS7006: Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type. in reactJs file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to write below code in ReactJs - typescrpit file(index.tsx)

```
props.emplList.findIndex(i => i.manager === false);
```

I have already tried

```
props.emplList.findIndex((i:any) => {i.manager === false});
```

but it will **return -1** which is incorrect. Expected value is > 0

How to write this line with compitable with tsx file? 
How to resolve this error **Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type** will be solve ?

Comment: What do you ask exactly? `-1` is a valid return value from `findIndex`, meaning "nothing found". So nothing was found in your case. (Also side comment: if you put `any` instead of proper type just to silence a warning, why do you bother to use TypeScript at all?)

Comment: no, answer is 5 but is returning as -1

Comment: Because your test is wrong. The computer does exactly what you've asked. It should be `(i.manager === false)` or the function you supply returns `undefined` and no elements are found, obviously.

Comment: `(i => {i === 1})(1);` will be `undefined`; `(i => (i === 1))(1);` will be `true`

Comment: @avysk - i needs some type here, eventhough it is taking any implicitly but it didn't work. ihave tested this in console of browser and it is working as i mentioned in que first code

Comment: Types do not affect how the code is executed. You wrote non-working JavaScirpt because your filter function returns `undefined` -- it won't work with TypeScript either, no matter what types you add. Start with fixing the filter function definition.